# Composition of a natural transformations with a functor--whiskering

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors, natural-transformations

If $M$ is an endofunctor on a category $\cal K$ and $\eta:Id_{\cal K}\to M$
is a natural transorfmation, what is the difference between $\eta M$ and $M\eta$, and how these two (componentwise) are defined on an object $A$ in $\cal K$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\eta M)_A=\eta_{M(A)}$ and $(M\eta)_A=M(\eta_A)$

Comment: Great. Will somethig change in your formulas if the n.t. $\eta$ were not from an Identity, but from a general endofunctor $F$ on $\cal K$ ?

Comment: Not essentially. It is in general that the component of $\sigma G$ and $G\sigma$ on object $A$ are $\sigma_{G(A)}$ and $G(\sigma_A)$ respectively (where $\sigma$ denotes a natural transformation and $G$ a functor. It is by definition.

Comment: Could you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3283300/composition-of-a-natural-transformation-with-a-functor) question ?