# Composition of a natural transformation with a functor

Tags: category-theory, functors, diagram-chasing, natural-transformations

I have asked a similar question [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282979/composition-of-a-natural-transformations-with-a-functor-whiskering/) but still in the snippet below, I don't know what is the functor $G$ and how differs
$(G\ast\omega_F)$ from $(\omega_G\ast F)$ , what are they and what is $\cdot$ here.

[image]

Comment: You should cite your sources.

Comment: This a page from a paper by Rosicky Adamek: Algebra and Local Presentability--how algebraic are. Is this citation OK ?

Comment: I said this recently to someone working on a similar paper-you should learn the basics of 2-category theory before trying to read a paper using them. For a hint, if $G:\mathcal W\to \mathcal X$ then $G*\omega_F:\mathcal V^{\mathcal K}\to \mathcal X$ is a natural isomorphism that has only one possible definition. The $\cdot$ is just composition.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Haven't you somehow mixed up $\cal W$ and $\cal V$. So is $G$ from  $\cal W$ or from $\cal V$ ? Thank you. To you advice, yes, I'm going to learn  the basics of 2-category theory from Riehel and ncatlab.

Comment: I'm learning from [this](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~tarlecki/teaching/ct/slides/fnats.pdf) page 110. Could you please explain what is your $G,\cal W,V, X$ on that page there?

Comment: @user335120 No error, $G$ comes after $F$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I still struggle with that equation below the square. I don't know e.g.  why $\omega_G\ast F:\cal V \to V^K$, could this be easily said with the help of the definition of $\ast$ which should be the horizontal composition of n.t. [here](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~tarlecki/teaching/ct/slides/fnats.pdf) on the page 110?

Comment: @user3357120 Yes, exactly this is a horizontal composition. The trick is that since $F$ is a functor, not a natural transformation, this is an abusive notation for $\omega_F*\mathrm{id}_F$. On the other hand this operation of composing a functor with a natural transformation is so common that it's often considered under the separate name of "whiskering", and in fact horizontal composition itself may be defined in terms of vertical composition and whiskering.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ok. And is $\omega_G\ast id_F:\cal V\to V^K$ completelly all right (ie. its domain and codomain)?

Comment: @KevinCarlson And finally is the component of $\omega_G \ast F$ at $A$ equal to $F(\omega_{(GA)})$ ?